# Declaring a variable name that contains the contents of another variable in C

Tags: c, variables, dynamic, names

I am working on a project that requires that I name a structure array variable with a predetermined prefix and then a number.  The program starts off with an array that looks like this:

```
foo[elements]
```

and I need to declare something like this:

```
foo1[elements+1]
```

I can't just declare `foo1[elements+1]` because there is no predetermined number of new arrays with larger contents because I will be iterating through a loop.  If I need to present more information, or if I am not clearly presenting my question, please tell me.  I don't know if this is even possible, but if it is, it will certainly shorten things up for me.

Comment: In C, All types must be known at compile time. Change Your design...

Comment: Same goes for variable names

Comment: You can dynamically create variables, using malloc, to create a variable length array.  Also, you can use preprocessor glue to change the names of variables (appending a number to the end), but as hyde has said, this must be known at compile time.

Comment: What comes to mind is to use a #define to assign elements to something. Is it possible to explain the use-case for this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem of dynamically allocating memory for an unknown number of elements. The key here is **dynamic memory**, so you have to keep track of your own memory chunks. You'll have to use at some point `malloc()` and `free()`.

Depending on your needs, `elements` type, what you can do is:

1. If `elements` are a single value, maybe an integer. A good option is dynamically allocated arrays, see [Sergey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20101891/7852) for a code snippet.
2. If `elements` is a more complex structure, with a few fields. You can use a list or array that holds the references to your N lists. something like:

> ```
>  foo[0] -> fooN[0] -> ... -> fooN[N]
>     .        |                |
>     .      element 0         element N
>     .
>  foo[M] -> fooN[0] -> ... -> fooN[N]
>              |                | 
>            element 0         element N
> ```

If M is known before hand, you can use an array. If neither M or N are unknown, you'll be using nested [linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). That is a linked list of linked lists.

You'll find TONS of C linked list implementations on the web.

Answer (score 3):

In C variable names have to be known at compile time. There is no way to create new variable names at run time. Not the right language.

Your best bet will be to allocate an array that will hold your arrays:

```
int ** foo = calloc(sizeof(*foo), numarrays);
for (i = 0; i < numarrays; i++)
    foo[i] = calloc(sizeof(**foo), elements + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't allocate foo1 statically, like foo1[elements+1], unless the value of elements is not something that you would only know at runtime. 
If you do know the number of elements you want than don't use a variable in the declaration:

```
#define ELEMENTS 10
```

int foo[ELEMENTS];
   int foo1[ELEMENTS+1];

Or, if it is something you would no at runtime, use dynamic memory allocation

```
int *foo, *foo1;

foo = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)* elements);
foo1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*( elements+1 ) );
```

and don't forget to free the memory one you are done:

```
free(foo);
free(foo1);
```